# Почему действия с RichEdit1 происходит, а с NewRichEdit - нет?

Tags: delphi

```
procedure TForm1.BoldClick(Sender: TObject);
    var
    NewRichEdit: TRichEdit;
begin
    NewRichEdit := TRichEdit.Create(nil);
    try
        RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Style:=[fsBold];
        NewRichEdit.SelAttributes.Style:=[fsBold];
    finally
        NewRichEdit.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Что вы имеете ввиду под "действия"? 
Судя по вашим записям, объект `NewRichEdit` создан но:

1. Не проинициализирован до конца
2. Не положен на форму

Т.е. по меньшей мере вам еще нужно сделать вот что:

```
//Имхо, для работы с формами лучше создавать так
NewRichEdit = TRichEdit.Create(self);
NewRichEdit.Parent(self);
NewRichEdit.Visible(true);
//позиционировать на форме и так далее... желательно еще имя ему дать (уникальное)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну, и еще добавлю, что при такой структуре

```
NewRichEdit := TRichEdit.Create(nil);
try
    ...  
finally
    NewRichEdit.Free;
end;
```

обект NewRichEdit будет удален сразу после завершения действий и вы ничего не увидите.

```
NewRichEdit.Free;
```

Нужно делать тогда, когда NewRichEdit уже не нужен, например, в TForm1.FormDestroy.